# MYSQL IF statement to different WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to solve a question on my app, i have this query to try to make it work.

```
SELECT * FROM articles
(IF articles.type = 1, INNER JOIN members ON members.id_member = articles.author_id,
INNER JOIN company ON company.id_company = articles.author_id) AS user
WHERE articles.tipe = '1' AND  user = '1';
```

I have a systems that post articles, but the same user can post on his name or in the name of a company that he has created, so, What i'm trying to do is, if the articles.tipe is type 1, then the article was published by his company, and if otherwise, it's type 0, then it's posted by him on his own name, if i only use 1 of them, they will get mixed, i've tryed different approches but none of them seem to work for me, can anybody help please?

Comment: you cannot conditionally join tables like that. it's a flat-out syntax error. you **CAN** put the if() conditions into the join clause, however. `left join on .... and articles.type=1`. Any records which don't qualityw ill simply show up as `NULL` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get records for both article_type=0 and article_type=1 with conditional joins based on article type, here is the query:

```
select * from (

  select article.type,article.name,member.name as user from articles INNER JOIN members                         ON members.id_member = articles.author_id where article_type=0

 UNION ALL

 select article.type,article.name,company.name as user from articles INNER JOIN members       ON members.id_member = articles.author_id INNER JOIN company ON company.id_company = articles.author_id  where article_type=1
```

) as tmptbl;

Answer (score 0):

You can left join both tables. For each articles record, one of the joined records will have values, the other will have all nulls. You can use coalesce on the columns or a case expression.

```
SELECT a.*, coalesce(m.name,c.name) as username
FROM articles a
LEFT JOIN members m ON m.id_member = a.author_id and a.type = '0'
LEFT JOIN company c ON c.id_company = a.author_id and a.type = '1'
WHERE a.user = '1';
```

Comment: i see your point, but in this case, the same 'articles.type' is never null, is 0 or 1

Comment: No, you don't see the point. articles.type is either 0 or 1. I outer join two records, a member record and a company record to each articles record. One will match and contain data. The other will be left joined and contain nulls instead of data.

Comment: the query works, bu it just gives-me wrong records, i'm trying to make another join, because i have a $_SESSION var whit the user id, and the company has a an FK whit the same id so i can know from who the company is, ignore the names `SELECT a.*, coalesce(m.id_member,c.id_empresa) as username
FROM artigo AS a
LEFT JOIN members m ON m.id_member = a.autor_id and a.tipo = '0'
LEFT JOIN empresa c ON c.id_empresa = a.autor_id and a.tipo = '1'
INNER JOIN members ON members.id_member = c.id_member
WHERE members.id_member = '1';`

Answer (score 0):

you should use inner join to fetch only articles which have member id and company id for article type=1. so article_type condition will come in where condition and we will use inner join with member and company table.

Following query will give all the articles which have article type

```
select * from articles INNER JOIN members ON members.id_member = articles.author_id INNER JOIN company ON company.id_company = articles.author_id  where articles.type=1 and user=1
```

please add some more clarification if you think i am not understanding your question properly. Hope this helps you.

Comment: in your answer, you select by type, my problem is, the same user can have type 0 and type 1, the only thing that changes is that you can have articles publishid by those two, the aswe that @Thorsten Kettner gave is almos rigth there, because it choses wheter is type 0 and the search will be by the user id or type 1 and the company id witch by it's side, has an id_member inside that point to the same user, i'm i expressing correctly? it's kind of messi trying to explain... sorry

Comment: following query will fetch result for both the cases:          select * from (

select article.type,article.name,member.name as user from articles INNER JOIN members ON members.id_member = articles.author_id where article_type=0

UNION ALL

select article.type,article.name,company.name as user from articles INNER JOIN members ON members.id_member = articles.author_id INNER JOIN company ON company.id_company = articles.author_id  where article_type=1




) as tmptbl;

Comment: thanks mate :) it works now :) i just added on both were clauses that the id_member had to be the user primar id (FK on company table) and it's stored on $_SESSION var so, the query works with that id, answer with that and i'll make it accepted answer :)